# Angular application error in IE 11. Everything works fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing an angular application. The application is working fine in Chrome but in IE( I am using IE11) I am getting the following error.

```
Unhandled exception at line 2930, column 1 in http://localhost:54896/Scripts/Angular/angular.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'prototype' of undefined or null reference
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this meta tag in the head of your html file index:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

This will force the browser to render with the latest version documents.