# Angular 7 application gives error in IE 11 and works fine in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an application in angular 7 works fine in other browsers but fails to load in IE11

I have also added the below line from the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40364829/angular-application-error-in-ie-11-everything-works-fine-in-chrome) but still doesn't work for me.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

I have also searched for more specific causes of the error 
Given below are my dependencies. Any workaround for IE 11?

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^7.0.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.8.5",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.14",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng2-archwizard": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^4.3.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4",
    "qs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "tether": "1.4.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.4",
    "@angular/cli": "7.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.5",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.21",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.117",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.2.19",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.7.35",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.0",
    "all-contributors-cli": "^5.4.1",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.2.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.3.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.1"
  }
```

The error that I get in the console is 
[image]

Comment: Its syntax error it seems. Need to have a look at code.

Comment: probably need transpiled code for IE, since it doesn't understand new syntax, like for example `someobj = { func: function() { ...} }` can be written using *Shorthand method names (ES2015)* like `someobj = { func() { ...} }` which would throw the exact error `Expected ':'`

Comment: @Bravo How would I go about resolving it. It shows Expected ':' at `return{i,v:n}}return{i:-1,` 

and next error at `{setTimeout(()=>{throw e},0)}const o={closed:!0,next(e){}`

Comment: oh, yes, that's another syntax IE11 doesn't understand `Shorthand property names (ES2015)` - so, yes, you'll need a transpiler - I don't know how to add transpiling to angular - there's probably documentation out there

Comment: @Bravo  Thanks will check for ways to add transpiling to angular.

Comment: Angular's browser support and how to polyfill for outdated browsers is described very well in the official Angular docs: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: I solved It using the link [medium](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-and-internet-explorer-5e59bb6fb4e9)
In my polyfill.ts uncommented a set of lines. And my application works on IE 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Angular and Internet Explorer](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-and-internet-explorer-5e59bb6fb4e9) I un-commented the below import statement in polyfill.ts and it worked in IE11

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Initially the above lines were commented in polyfill.ts